# Error: Lexical or preprocessor issue when trying to import external framework

Tags: ios5, xcode4.2

When i try to import external framework (named Mappy), i git an error in the build and run phase:

```
Lexical or preprocessor issue
'MappyKit/MappyKit.h' file not found.
```

The obvious thinking say that the MappyKit.h file is missing. However, it does exist in the framework folder.
So, please, what kind of issue is that? i am struggling with that for days.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it means just like the error says " 'MappyKit/MappyKit.h' file not found. " So import that file into your folders. Also make sure you are importing it correctly.

```
#import <something> 
vs
#import "something"
```

Though I have had issues were it was working one build and then getting this error the next. Which i managed to clean my build and it fixed it.

To see if you actually connected the external frameworks, you can hover over `#import <something>` and hold down `command->left click` if that opens up your imported file, then you imported correctly!